# Pathfigure in wpf

Tags: wpf, pathgeometry

How to get exact Pathfigure instance once we click on a Path? My Path has multiple pathFigures. I have following Xaml code:

```
    <Path Stroke="Black">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="5,5">
                    <LineSegment Point="10,10"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="20,60"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="70,90"/>
                </PathFigure>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="20,60">
                    <LineSegment Point="30,20"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="40,70"/>
                    <LineSegment Point="70,80"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
```